# Normalization for the Fourier series of a Gaussian Electric field

Tags: fourier-transform, normalization

I have a function $f(x) = \exp(-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2})$ on a box of size $L$. I have the given relation between the size of the box and the width of the Gaussian $\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}L$. I use the following definition for the Fourier coefficients:

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L \exp(-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2})\exp(\frac{-in\pi x}{L}) dx$$

For my purpose, $L \gg \sigma$, so I use instead:

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2})\exp(\frac{-in\pi x}{L}) dx$$

The computation of the fourier series gives:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(\frac{-n^2}{\left(2L/\pi\sigma\right)^2})\exp(in\pi x/L)$$

I want to check the unitarity of this decomposition, that is, if the $\mathcal{L}^2$ norm remains the same. For the original representation, I find:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2(x) dx = \sigma\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} = L$$

For the Fourier series, the calculation is a bit more detailed:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}n\sum_{n'=-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-\left(\frac{\pi\sigma}{2L}\right)^2(n^2+n'^2))\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp(\frac{i\pi x}{L}(n+n'))dx$$

which simplifies to:

$$\frac{L}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{n'=-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}(n^2+n'^2)\right) 2\pi\delta(n+n')$$

We can reduce the sum to:

$$L\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-n^2\pi\right)$$

It's unclear to me how to proceed further. I can't be sure that this conundrum isn't because of my initial approximation $L \gg \sigma$. Any insight is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT 1: I am aware that the approximation $L \gg \sigma$ in this case is 'unholy', but I am looking for simple approximations that will do the job upto a quantifiable error, as opposed to dealing with messy, complex-argument error functions. I am open to alternative solutions.

Comment: I haven't checked the math, but you cannot really take the approximation if you know that $L = \sqrt{\pi/2}\sigma$.

Comment: Not taking the approximation means dealing with complex-valued error functions that are messy to handle (ref. Mathematica). I am looking for a simple approximation that will do the job (up to some accuracy that can be quantified). In this case $L > \sigma$ holds and should not lead to an entirely absurd result like this, hence the question.

Comment: if you write $e^{n\pi x}$ as $\cos{n\pi x}$ + i$\sin{n\pi x}$ you should have real error functions. Or transform a gaussian (to another gaussian), and convolve it with a sinc function, which is multiplication by a box in the other domain.